# How do I bind a ViewModel to a Collationview?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I'm trying to bind a view model to a collection view. But I don't know how to do it. I'm using MVVM pattern and RxSwift, and I've only tried table view binding before. Here's my view model and the view controller code I've done so far.

```
class SearchViewModel: ViewModelType {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    struct input {
        let loadData: Signal<Void>
    }

    struct output {
        let result: Signal<String>
        let loadApplyList: PublishRelay<friends>
    }

    func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = SearchAPI()
        let result = PublishSubject<String>()
        let loadApplyList = PublishRelay<friends>()

        input.loadData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            api.getFriend().subscribe(onNext: { (response, statuscode) in
                switch statuscode {
                case .ok:
                    if let response = response {
                        loadApplyList.accept(response)
                    }
                default:
                    print("default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        return output(result: result.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ""), loadApplyList: loadApplyList)
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel code

```
func bindViewModel() {
       let input = SearchViewModel.input(loadData: loadData.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ()))
       let output = viewModel.transform(input)
       
   }
```

And this is my ViewController code.
How should the collection view bind?

Comment: are you intending to use `RxDataSource`? or simply implement collection view delegates on your won and return values for those delegates based on `loadApplyList` value?

Comment: A collection view needs an array of items. Is there an array in this `friends` type? We need more details on this type.

Comment: @DanielT. In the friend array, the email, name, and image are string values.

Comment: @earth There are no arrays in your code. Where is this "friend array"?

Comment: @DanielT. There is a file named friendModel because it used an mvvm pattern. There's an array of friends in this file.

Comment: Again, there is _no_ array in the code you posted above.

Comment: struct friends: Codable {
    let friends: [User]
} This is friends. Is there a problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your view model should look like:

```
class SearchViewModel {
    // no need for a disposedBag. If you are putting a disposeBag in your view model, you are likely doing something wrong.

    struct input {
        let loadData: Signal<Void>
    }

    struct output {
        let loadApplyList: Driver<[User]> // you should be passing an array here, not an object.
    }

    func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = SearchAPI()

        let friendResult = input.loadData
            .flatMapLatest {
                api.getFriend()
                    .compactMap { $0.0.map(Result<friends, Error>.success) }
                    .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { Driver.just(Result<friends, Error>.failure($0)) })
            }

        let loadApplyList = friendResult
            .compactMap { (result) -> [User]? in
                guard case let .success(list) = result else { return nil }
                return list.friends
            }

        return output(loadApplyList: loadApplyList)
    }
}
```

Now in your view controller, you can bind it like this:

```
func bindViewModel() {
    let input = SearchViewModel.input(loadData: loadData.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ()))
    let output = viewModel.transform(input)

    output.loadApplyList
        .drive(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: MyCellType.self)) { index, item, cell in
            // configure cell with item here
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```